# Shiny WebApp and UI: add style and dropdown menu in the header

Tags: r, shiny

I'm just starting using R and Shiny App and I'm a bit confused about how to achieve what I'm trying to do. I want to change the UI of my Shiny App. As a `C#` developer, I work with `HTML`/`CSS`, `AdminLTE` and so on. I can't find a proper documentation how to change the UI in a Shiny App.

What I want to achieve in the UI is something like the following image:

[image: My idea]

First, I removed the sidebar. Now, my problem is to box the UI. In the header, I want to add a dropdown menu with few options. Then, I want in the middle of the page to have a panel with 2 column: in the first column first row I desire to see the graph generate by `R`, then same text around it to explain the graph.

On top of that, I want to change the style for example of tabs or buttons.

After 2 days of work, I wrote this code but it is very far from what I want to achieve.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
 
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- navbarPage(
    "Test",
    tabPanel(
        "Introduction",
        titlePanel(
            div(
                windowTitle = "Test window"
            )
        ),
        div(class = "my-class", 
            h3("LAI287 basal insulin study"),
            p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."),
            p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."),
            actionButton(
                inputId = "btnStart",
                label = "Start analysis",
                className = "btn-primary"
            )
        )
    ),
    tabPanel(
        "Attribute specification"
    ),
    tabPanel(
        dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                     notificationItem(
                         text = "5 new users today",
                         icon("users")
                     ),
                     notificationItem(
                         text = "12 items delivered",
                         icon("truck"),
                         status = "success"
                     ),
                     notificationItem(
                         text = "Server load at 86%",
                         icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                         status = "warning"
                     )
        )
    )
)
 
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
 
        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}
 
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The result of this code is in the following screenshot. The only dropdown I found was for *messages* or *notifications*.

[image]

I know [AdminLTE](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/net-core/integrating-adminlte-with-asp-net-core/) quite well but I don't understand how to write the code for Shiny App. Do you have any idea or suggestion how I can implement this UI? Is there any good tutorial I can read?

### Update

I found some documentation on [RStudio Shiny dashboard](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html). First, I don't understand the difference between **dashboardPage** and **navbarPage**. Can I add a **navbarPage** to a **dashboardPage**?

From the documentation, I added this code:

```
box(
  title = "Histogram", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
  collapsible = TRUE,
  plotOutput("plot3", height = 250)
),

box(
  title = "Inputs", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE,
  "Box content here", br(), "More box content",
  sliderInput("slider", "Slider input:", 1, 100, 50),
  textInput("text", "Text input:")
)
```

and I expect something like

[image]

but my result is like that (thanks [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13241545/jan) for the menu)

[image]

I saw on the other page of the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html) that it is possible to add

```
dashboardPage(skin = "blue")
```

but in my case I don't have a **dashboardPage**.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the `navbarMenu` function? You can add menu items to the `navbarPage` with it:

```
navbarPage("App Title",
  tabPanel("Plot"),
  navbarMenu("More",
    tabPanel("Summary"),
    "----",
    "Section header",
    tabPanel("Table")
  )
)
```

Layouting can be done with fluid layouts, e.g.

```
fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
      "4"
    ),
    column(width = 3, offset = 2,
      "3 offset 2"
    )
```

See the [layout guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) for the necessary details.

Comment: Thank you, this is the first part :) How can I box the page? How can I add the frame in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with AdminLTE then I strongly recommend using [bs4Dash](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/articles/bs4Dash.html).  It is a very robust package that allows for the use of boxes and other features that are regularly a part of AdminLTE (including Bootstrap 4).  But the core of the language is still Shiny, so you may need to work through a few basic examples before attempting anything with greater complexity.

You can change colors, font-sizes, etc. in bs4Dash [by following the instructions on this page](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/articles/more-skins.html).

For a demo of what is possible, [see here](https://dgranjon.shinyapps.io/bs4DashDemo/).

I've provided a very basic example at the bottom of this answer.

Otherwise adding a dropdown navigation in bs4Dash is a bit tricky, and will require a combination of Javascript, CSS, and HTML.  Luckily, you can modify all of these things.

Good luck!

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(
        leftUi = tagList(
            dropdownMenu(
                badgeStatus = "info",
                type = "notifications",
                notificationItem(
                    inputId = "notice1",
                    text = "Put text here!",
                    status = "danger"
                )
            ),
            dropdownMenu(
                badgeStatus = "info",
                type = "tasks",
                taskItem(
                    inputId = "notice2",
                    text = "My progress",
                    color = "orange",
                    value = 10
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
            body = dashboardBody(
            fluidRow(
                column(width = 8,
                       box(width = NULL, title = "Old Faithful Geyser Data",
                           collapsible = F,
                           wellPanel( sliderInput("bins",
                                                  "Number of bins:",
                                                  min = 1,
                                                  max = 50,
                                                  value = 30)),
                           plotOutput("distPlot")
                       ),
                       box(width = NULL, title = NULL, collapsible = F,
                          fluidRow(
                              column(width = 5,
                                     tags$img(src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/EslMF.png", width = '100%')
                                     ),
                              column(width = 7,
                                     tags$h4("Card Title"),
                                     tags$p("Some text here")
                              )
                          )
                       )
                
                      ),
                column(width = 4,
                       box(width = NULL, title = "Header", status = "info", collapsible = F),
                       box(width = NULL, title = "Header", status = "success", collapsible = F),
                       box(width = NULL, title = "Header", status = "secondary", collapsible = F)
                       )
                     )
                ),
            controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
                collapsed = FALSE,
                div(class = "p-3", skinSelector()),
                pinned = TRUE
            )
            )

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```